# Retrieve data from Firebase by date

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app stores meetups in Firebase. Each meetup has an end date that has been converted to a string and saved in Firebase as an attribute of the meetup (see image). When the app retrieves the data from Firebase it pulls all the meetups into an array and filters out the meetups if the end date is in the past. I am trying to find a way to query Firebase where it only pulls meetups with an end date equal to or greater than the current date. Meetups with end dates in the past are not needed and will never be shown on the app, plus it increases the network bandwidth used to download the meetups. Does anyone have any solutions/suggestions on how exclude meetups from the query so that I don't have to filter out the meetups on the client side?[image]

Comment: Store `startDate` and `endDate` as Unix timestamp so that you would be able to compare it.

Comment: @triple.s thanks! I will try this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase offers a bunch of querying and limiting functions here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_database_query#a5d089e583013c7cdcd653f974e2cba56

If I am not mistaken, you should be able to build a limited query of meetups like so

```
ref.child("meetups").queryOrderedByChild("endDate").queryStartingAtValue(currentDate).queryEndingAtValue(currentDate).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in
   //do something     
})
```

**Edit**

You're going to want to store the startDate and endDate fields as timestamps

Comment: Thank you so much. I am going to try this out and will update the answer with how it works.

Comment: Can you please explain why .queryEndingAtValue(currentDate) is included?

Comment: Yup thats incorrect, good catch. All you should need is queryStartingAtValue since you want endDates equal to and greater than the current date.